# Tag Synonym Request Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I recently wanted to browse some questions about Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate and I typed in `[mh3u]` but I was surprised that it showed 0 results.

I'd like to propose the tag Synonym [mh3u](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mh3u) for [monster-hunter-3-ultimate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-3-ultimate) since MH3U is used basically everywhere on the internet. The full name is really long and most people who use google will also search for mh3u and not for Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see why not. Tags synonimised.